# Find all tiles intersected by line segment

Tags: c++, math, optimization

I have to find all tiles that intersected by line segment but Bresenham's line algorithm doesnt fit to my requirements. I need to find all cells. I dont need to know intersection points, only the fact of intersection. Thanks for help.

I thought to find direction vector of line and step by step find cells by division on tile size. But i dont know how to select correct step size. 1 px step is bad i think.

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't fit into my requirements? In what way does it not fit?

Comment: It will not find all cells only that fir into delta parameter. Look at wikipedia's example image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Here is article](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~amana/research/grid.pdf) of Amanatides and Woo "A Fast Voxel Traversal Algorithm for Ray Tracing" for 2D and 3D cases. [Practical implementation.](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Raytracing_Topics_Techniques-Part_4_Spatial_Subdivisions.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

You might use one of the many line equations found at: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Calculus/StraightLine.shtml or http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Line.html

Supposedly you have your line in your coordinate system going through two points you deduce the `y=mx+n` equation and just match against your tiles and see if they intersect while moving x in the unit of your coordinate system in any direction you prefer from the smallest x of your tiles till the biggest. If your coordinate system is the screen, 1 pixel should be enough.

This is the closes I can hint right know without knowing more about the exact nature of the problem you are facing.

Comment: What means "match against your tiles"? I need algorithm for exactly this operation.

Comment: what geometrical shape are your tiles?

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to modify the Bresenham's algorithm such that it tracks what you need. Here's the relevant fragment of the algorithm:

```
plot(x,y);
error = error + deltaerr;
if (error >= 0.5)
{
    y = y + ystep;
    error = error - 1.0;
}
```

To keep track of all the cells we need another variable. Note tat I have not rigorously checked this.

```
plot(x,y);
olderror = error.
error = error + deltaerr;
if (error >= 0.5)
{
    y = y + ystep;
    error = error - 1.0;
    extra = error+olderror;

    if (extra > 0)
    {
      plot (x,y); /* not plot (x-1,y); */
    }
    else if (extra < 0)
    {
      plot (x+1,y-1); /* not plot (x+1,y); */
    }
    else
    {
      // the line goes right through the cell corner
      // either do nothing, or do both plot (x-1,y) and plot (x+1,y)
      // depending on your definition of intersection           
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll try it later i will report about results

Comment: There's an error in `plot (x-1,y)` and `plot (x+1,y)`. The coordinates are wrong. It should be `plot (x,y)` and `plot (x+1,y-1)`. I have updated the code.

Comment: Also, if steep lines are handled, `plot(x,y)` becomes `if (steep) plot(y,x); else plot(x,y);`, and other `plot` calls change similarly (like in the second listing in the wikipedia article).
`